# Connect an HTML Drop Down List to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am looking to connect an HTML form to a Cosmos document rather than having static data.  Can anyone guide me in the right direction?  This is what I have for static data, I have a local db set up for testing.  Thanks for any assistance.

```js
    var select = document.getElementById("ClosurePlanList"),
        arr = ["test1","test2","test3"];
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
            txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
            option.appendChild(txt);
            option.setAttribute("value",arr[i]);
            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
        }
```

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-application#_Toc395783181

Comment: Hi, has your issue been solved? Or do you need assistances ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls tru the steps below :

Step 1 :Host a nodejs backend locally to query CosmosDB for you, try the code below :

```
var express = require('express');
const { CosmosClient } = require("@azure/cosmos");
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
});


const endpoint = "<your cosmos db endpoint>"
const key = "<your cosmos db key>"
const dbId = "<DB ID/name>"
const containerId = "<container ID/name>"


app.get('/getData', function (req, res) {
    getData().then(
        (FeedResponse)=>{
            res.end(JSON.stringify(FeedResponse.resources));
        },
        (err)=>{
            console.log(err);
            res.end("err");
        });

})

 function getData(){
    const client = new CosmosClient({
        endpoint,
        key
      });

    const container = client.database(dbId).container(containerId);
    const options = {
        maxItemCount: 10000,
        maxDegreeOfParallelism: 1000,
        bufferItems: true
      };
    const query = "select c.id,c.name from c";

    return container.items.query(query, options).fetchAll();
}

var server = app.listen(8888, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

After you run it , you can get your cosmos db data from `http://localhost:8888/getData` .

Result from the nodejs backend :

[image]

This is the data I get from my cosmos db using the query in above code :
[image]

Step 2: Try the HTML code below to fulfill the options values of your select tag from cosmosdb :

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        Plan: <select id = "ClosurePlanList">
    </div>

</body>
<script>
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8888/getData');
    var select = document.getElementById("ClosurePlanList");
    xhr.send();


    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status != 200) { // analyze HTTP status of the response
        alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found
      } else { // show the result

        arr = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
            txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i].name);
            option.appendChild(txt);
            option.setAttribute("value",arr[i].id);
            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
        }
      }
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Result : 
[image]

Getting data from cosmosdb from static html page by js code directly is not recommanded as you could leak your cosmosdb credentials.

Hope it helps!