# How to read from multiple CosmosDB documents

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am stuck trying to figure out how to get my list to read from a specific query.  If I comment out one of the app.get it reads from one DocumentDB and vice versa.  How do I get it to read both my queries at the same time or specify one list to read from one query and another to read from a second query?  I attempted a second querySpec, not sure if that is the way to go though.

Thank you

I was able to get assistance from my previous question.
[Connecting to multiple CosmosDB documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379901/connecting-to-multiple-cosmosdb-documents)

Original tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-application#_Toc395783181

Code in tasklist.js

```
const TaskDao = require("../models/taskDao");

 class TaskList {
   /**
    * Handles the various APIs for displaying and managing tasks
    * @param {TaskDao} taskDao
    */
   constructor(taskDao,taskDao2) {
     this.taskDao = taskDao;
     this.taskDao2 = taskDao2;
   }

   async showList1(req, res) {
    const querySpec = {
      query: "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.List1=@List1",
      parameters: [
        {
          name: "@List1",
          value: "yes"
        }
      ]

    };

     const items = await this.taskDao2.find(querySpec);
     res.render("index", {
       title: "Form",
       tasks: items
     });

   }


   async showList2(req, res) {
    const querySpec2 = {
      query: "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.List2=@List2",
       parameters: [
         {
           name: "@List2",
           value: true
        }
      ]
    };

     const items = await this.taskDao.find(querySpec2);
     res.render("index", {
       title: "Form",
       tasks: items
     });

   }

   async addTask(req, res) {
     const item = req.body;

     await this.taskDao.addItem(item);
     res.redirect("/");
   }
 }

 module.exports = TaskList;
```

Code in app.js

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => taskList.showList1(req, res).catch(next))
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => taskList.showList2(req, res).catch(next))
```

I would like for these lists to read different values.

[image]

Comment: I am not so clear about what you want. Are users will select an option in List1 and List2 will load options from another collection based on what users select in List1?

Comment: I’d like one list to read from one DocumentDB and a second list to read from another DocumentDB. The collections don’t have to be based on previous selection.  So each list will have its own query.

Comment: Hi,has my answer solved your issue?

Comment: Is there anyway to do something like this?

`async find(querySpec, querySpec2) {
     debug('Querying for items from the database')
     if (!this.container) {
       throw new Error('Collection is not initialized.')
     }
     const { resources } = await this.container.items.query(querySpec,querySpec2).fetchAll()
     return resources
     
   }`

Comment: Hi @williswin if my answer is helpful for you, pls mark it as an answer. For your further queries , pls kindly post a new question and I'll assist you at the fist time I see it. Btw, pls be for specific in your new query so that I can assist you efficiently .Thanks!

Comment: Thanks I will create a new one. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to load data from two different containers to your HTMLselector, you should use `res.send` to send your data instead of `res.render`.

Try the steps below :
1. Go to `app.js`  add two route codes here :

```
 app.get('/list1', (req, res, next) => taskList.showTasks1(req, res).catch(next))
 app.get('/list2', (req, res, next) => taskList.showTasks2(req, res).catch(next))
```

[image]

2.Go to `routes/tasklist.js`, add `showTasks1` and `showTasks2`(this code is based on my previous answer `taskDao2` is needed here.) :

```
   async showTasks1(req, res) {
    const items = await this.taskDao.find("SELECT * FROM root r ");
    res.send(items);
  }
  async showTasks2(req, res) {
    const items = await this.taskDao2.find("SELECT * FROM root r ");
    res.send(items);
  }
```

[image]

Run this project, you can get data from your two containers by URL :

`http://localhost:3000/list1`  and `http://localhost:3000/list2`

[image]

Finally, just refer to my [first answer for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59329326/connect-an-html-drop-down-list-to-cosmos-db) to load data to selector.

Hope it helps. If you have any further concerns, pls feel free to let me know.